# Trying to make an image modal with AlpineJS & TailwindCSS, but I'm experiencing an issue

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

like the title can tell you already, I'm experiencing an issue when trying to create an image modal.

When I click the button that should open the image, it works fine, but when I click away and try to open it again, it does nothing. I couldn't find anything in the console that gives an error.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ lightbox: false, imgModalSrc : '', imgModalAlt : '', imgModalDesc : '' }">
  <button class="block w-24 p-3 mb-4 text-white bg-gray-600 rounded" @click="$dispatch('lightbox',  {  imgModalSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1000x700/066/f0f', imgModalAlt: 'First Image', imgModalDesc: 'Random Image One Description' })">#1</button>
  <button class="block w-24 p-3 text-white bg-gray-600 rounded" @click="$dispatch('lightbox',  {  imgModalSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1000x700/600/099' })">#2</button>

  <template @lightbox.window="lightbox = true; imgModalSrc = $event.detail.imgModalSrc; imgModalDesc = $event.detail.imgModalDesc;" x-if="lightbox">
    <div x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center w-full p-2 overflow-hidden bg-black bg-opacity-75 h-100">
      <div @click.away="lightbox = ''" class="">
        <img class="" :src="imgModalSrc" :alt="imgModalAlt">
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange race condition between the `x-if` and `@click.away`: when you click on the button second time it flips `lightbox` for a moment, then immediately `@click.away` flips it back, so you wont see the modal.

I'm not 100% sure what causes this, my guess is that since `x-if` actually removes/readds the respective element from the DOM tree, maybe for the second time its much faster, so at the same time, the `@click.away` also fires.

Anyways, ff you use `<div x-show="lightbox">` instead of `<template x-if="lightbox">` it's working fine. The `x-show` directive does remove the element from the DOM, just hides it with CSS.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ lightbox: false, imgModalSrc : '', imgModalAlt : '', imgModalDesc : '' }">
  <button class="block w-24 p-3 mb-4 text-white bg-gray-600 rounded" @click="$dispatch('lightbox',  {  imgModalSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1000x700/066/f0f', imgModalAlt: 'First Image', imgModalDesc: 'Random Image One Description' })">#1</button>
  <button class="block w-24 p-3 text-white bg-gray-600 rounded" @click="$dispatch('lightbox',  {  imgModalSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1000x700/600/099' })">#2</button>

  <div x-show="lightbox" @lightbox.window="lightbox = true; imgModalSrc = $event.detail.imgModalSrc; imgModalDesc = $event.detail.imgModalDesc;">
    <div x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 transform scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 transform scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform scale-90" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center w-full p-2 overflow-hidden bg-black bg-opacity-75 h-100">
      <div @click.away="lightbox = ''" class="">
        <img class="" :src="imgModalSrc" :alt="imgModalAlt">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
it's weird to me it doesn't work with template, but I'm happy you could help me with a solution. :)